# Regular expression syntax difficulties

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to learn regular expression testing in JavaScript but am finding it difficult to visualize. In my example below I am trying to test user input for a first name to make sure it doesn't have:

1. Numbers
2. Non-letter characters (symbols such as !, @, % for example)
3. No more than 1 blank space ('Sarah Jane' is ok, but 'Sarah  Jane' isn't)

This is my function so far, do any obvious syntax errors, especially in the reg expression stand out? Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function nameValidate() {
            var input = document.forms['myForm']['fName'].value;
            var re = /\d\s{2,}\W/;
            if (input == "") {             // Make sure there is something filled out
                document.getElementById('fNameError').style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById('fNameError').innerHTML = "** You must enter a name";
            }
            else if (re.test(input)) {
                document.getElementById('fNameError').style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById('fNameError').innerHTML = "** Names must contain only letters a-z or A-Z and no more than one space between names";
            }
        }   
    </script>
```

Comment: You can also change `if (input == "")` to `if (!input.length)`.

Comment: [A must read: Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description this regex will suit you better:

```
var re = /^[a-z]+( [a-z]+)?$/i;
```

And then inverse the `re.test` as:

```
else if (!re.test(input)) {
  document.getElementById('fNameError').style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById('fNameError').innerHTML = "** Names must contain only letters a-z or A-Z and no more than one space between names";
}
```

Comment: Do the brackets () in the reg expression allow you to group the internal contents? As in we grouped them in this example because the user may or may not input a second name preceded by a blank?

Comment: bracket expression is `( [a-z]+)?` where `?` makes it optional. So user can enter: `JohnSmith` OR `John Smith` and this regex will match both. But it won't match `John  Smith`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the regex for what you're asking:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?$/;
```

If it matches, it means the input is valid.

Explanation:

- `^`...`$` anchors the regex so it must match the entire string, and not just any substring inside it
- `[a-zA-Z]+` matches one or more consecutive letters
- `(?:`...`)` is just a grouping expression
- ... which contains a space and another `[a-zA-Z]+`
- ... and is optional thanks to the `?`

You could also apply variations if you wish, for example `[A-Z][a-z]*` instead of each `[a-zA-Z]+` would make sure each name starts with an uppercase letter and contains only lowercase letters after the first one.